# diffrent result in every run when using xgboost model in caret package

Tags: r, r-caret, xgboost, roc

I have unbalanced dataset (6% positive), I have used and xgboost model from caret package.

this is my code:

```
gbmGrid <- expand.grid(nrounds = 50,
                       eta = 0.4,
                       max_depth = 2,
                       gamma = 0,
                       colsample_bytree=0.8,
                       min_child_weight=1,
                       subsample=1)

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv",
                     number = 10,
                     search = "grid", 
                     fixedWindow = TRUE,
                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                     returnData = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "all",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     sampling = "smote",
                     selectionFunction = "best",
                     trim = FALSE,
                     allowParallel = TRUE)

classifier <- train(x = training_set[,-1],y = training_set[,1], method = 'xgbTree',metric = "ROC",trControl = ctrl,tuneGrid = gbmGrid)
```

the problem is that every time I "run" the train line it gives different roc, sensetivity and specificity.

```
  ROC       Sens       Spec     
  0.696084  0.8947368  0.2736111

  ROC        Sens       Spec     
  0.6655806  0.8917293  0.2444444
```

** the expand.grid is set on the best tune model.

does someone understand why the model isn't stable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vivek Kumar mentioned in his answer, boosting algorithms are stochastic algorithms. In addition, you are splitting your dataset with `trainControl`, which also introduces a source of randomness. Using `set.seed` to fix the inital randomness allows you to always get the same result, but it may be a lucky (or unlucky) one, so it is best to be avoided.

A better approach is to run the your code sample multiple times, for instance 10 times, until you are confident enough that the **mean** performance over multiple random initializations is correct. You can then report this mean (and ideally the standard deviation as well). In this case, do **not** use `set.seed` or you won't get any variation.

Comment: i'ts already doinf 10-fold cross validation, are you saying I need to do 10 fold with k reapets? and if so, what is the best number? I have heard 5x2 is pretty good.

Comment: @Ella yes actually you should always repeat the cross validation with different splits

Comment: so adjusting the cross validation to 5x2 its good or not Inhofe?

Comment: Not sure what is 5x2 exactly, but It's always the more the better.

Comment: it's 5 fold cross validation with 2 repeats.

Comment: You are always free to do more repeats if possible

Comment: @ella Now that you are trying to do repeats, do as many repeats as you want with cross-validation, but at that time, dont use the `set.seed()`. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the randomness in selecting the features for split by the xgboost.

Add the following line before your actual training code:

```
set.seed(100)
```

You can use any integer in place of 100.

This will set a seed for pseudorandom number generator, which will then generate exact same sequence of random numbers each time. So each time the code is called, the results will be same.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind if you have a small number of total samples, and the event you are trying to predict is small, the results can be very misleading. Any of the sets of results you get might be the best one for a given future prediction, but not for all future predictions. The best way to become consistent with 6% of a target class is to have a LOT of overall predictions so that you are training for something the model has seen more than 3 or 4 times.

Comment: @bethanyP  what do you mean by this sentence "have a LOT of overall predictions ".. can you elaborate?

Comment: that was bad English, I was in a hurry. My apologies If you have a ton observations (not predictions), then even 6% gives your model many opportunities to evaluate what those target observations are and increases the odds that your model will appropriately predict for them. My apologies,..I answered quickly on my way out the door!

Comment: @bethanyP I have 2018 observation, out of them 6% positive. it's not a lot at all.

Comment: A lot is going to depend on the complexity of the model, the number of variables, how much of the variability they explain and how well you tune it. You will just have to give it your best.